# Interpretation difficulty

Tags: meaning

I am reading a book by Carl Sagan, titled "Pale Blue Dot".

I bumped into a sentence which I can't figure out. So would you help me with it? The sentence goes,

> "Even members of hunter-gatherer groups-as far from the technological feats of our present global civilization ***as it is possible for humans to be***-solemnly describe their little band, whichever it is, as 'the people'.

***"As it is possible for humans to be"***, this sentence, seems to me extremely difficult to understand.

Would you rephrase it in an easy way?   Thanks for the help!

Comment: Typo? *Human*, not *haman*.

Answer (score 1):

Let's break down the complex sentence to its parts:

> Even members of hunter-gatherer groups

this should be straightforward: Sagan is talking about civilizations back in the nomadic days.

> as far from the technological feats of our present global civilization as it is possible for humans to be

The people in the early civilization had no technology that we "humans of today" have - even agriculture. That is as removed from technology as a human can be.

> solemnly describe their little band, whichever it is, as 'the people'.

Collectively referred to themselves as 'the people' (even without the established concepts that we have today of race, religion or nation).

Disclaimer: I have not read this book so I am simply interpreting the sentence. Therefore I'm not familiar with the context of the idea being discussed.

Comment: Wow, I can see that now. But as non-native speaker, it is not easy to find out the structure of the sentence.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: I'm not a native speaker myself; but had very good teachers early in life that instilled a love for the English language.  So don't let that bother you.